# Python: Ignore 'Incorrect padding' error when base64 decoding

Tags: python, base64

I have some data that is base64 encoded that I want to convert back to binary even if there is a padding error in it. If I use

```
base64.decodestring(b64_string)
```

it raises an 'Incorrect padding' error. Is there another way?

UPDATE: Thanks for all the feedback. To be honest, all the methods mentioned sounded a bit hit
and miss so I decided to try openssl. The following command worked a treat:

```
openssl enc -d -base64 -in b64string -out binary_data
```

Comment: Did you actually *TRY* using `base64.b64decode(strg, '-_')`? That is a priori, without you bothering to supply any sample data, the most likely Python solution to your problem. The "methods" proposed were DEBUG suggestions, NECESSARILY "hit and miss" given the paucity of the information supplied.

Comment: @John Machin: Yes, I did TRY your method but it didn't work. The data is company confidential.

Comment: Try `base64.urlsafe_b64decode(s)`

Comment: Could you provide the output of this: ```sorted(list(set(b64_string)))``` please?

Without revealing anything company-confidential, that should reveal which characters were used to encode the original data, which in turn may supply enough information to provide a non-hit-or-miss solution.

Comment: Yes, I know it's already solved, but, to be honest, the openssl solution also sounds hit-or-miss to me.

Comment: Whoops, my suggestion duplicates the one by @JohnMachin below.  Never mind!

Comment: I had the same issue, turned out it was a cache issue with chrome after following this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63571314/5034419 i was successful to get rid of this issue

Answer (score 163):

It seems you just need to add padding to your bytes before decoding. There are many other answers on this question, but I want to point out that (at least in Python 3.x) `base64.b64decode` will truncate any extra padding, provided there is enough in the first place.

So, something like: `b'abc='` works just as well as `b'abc=='` (as does `b'abc====='`).

What this means is that you can just add the maximum number of padding characters that you would ever need—which is two (`b'=='`)—and base64 will truncate any unnecessary ones.

This lets you write:

```py
base64.b64decode(s + b'==')
```

which is simpler than:

```py
base64.b64decode(s + b'=' * (-len(s) % 4))
```

---

Note that if the string `s` already has some padding (e.g. `b"aGVsbG8="`), this approach will only work if the `validate` keyword argument is set to `False` (which is the default). If `validate` is `True` this will result in a `binascii.Error` being raised if the total padding is longer than two characters.

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/base64.html#base64.b64decode):

> If *validate* is `False` (the default), characters that are neither in the normal base-64 alphabet nor the alternative alphabet are discarded prior to the padding check.  If *validate* is `True`, these non-alphabet characters in the input result in a `binascii.Error`.

However, if `validate` is `False` (or left blank to be the default) you can blindly add two padding characters without any problem. Thanks to eel ghEEz for pointing this out in the comments.

Comment: Okay that's not too "ugly" thanks :) By the way I think you never need more than 2 padding chars. Base64 algorithm works on groups of 3 chars at a time and only needs padding when your last group of chars is only 1 or 2 chars in length.

Comment: @Otto the padding here is for decoding, which works on groups of 4 chars. Base64 *encoding* works on groups of 3 chars :)

Comment: but if you know that during encoding maximally 2 will ever be added, which may become "lost" later, forcing you to re-add them before decoding, then you know you will only need to add maximally 2 during decoding too. #ChristmasTimeArgumentForTheFunOfIt

Comment: @Otto I believe you are right. While a base64 encoded string with length, for example, 5 would require 3 padding characters, a string of length 5 is not even a valid length for a base64 encoded string. You'd get the error: `binascii.Error: Invalid base64-encoded string: number of data characters (5) cannot be 1 more than a multiple of 4`. Thanks for pointing this out!

Comment: Unfortunately Python3's decoder is too strict about trailing equal signs, allowing no more than 2 of them, so blind addition of 2 equal signs may result in an exception if the encoded string already contained trailing equal signs.  As to why there is never a need of 3 trailing signs, one needs to understand that each encoding letter covers only 6 bits.  So while each 3 unencoded bytes encode into 4 letters, 1 or 2 unencoded bytes need 2 or 3 letters.  This means one needs to pad the encoded result with 2 or 1 equal signs (just to satisfy silly or exceedingly strict decoders).

Comment: @eelghEEz I haven't found that to be true, can you reproduce the exception?

Comment: @HenryWoody, `grep -A23 "def b64decode" /usr/lib/python3.10/base64.py` https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.10.9/Lib/base64.py#L85 shows a regex `b'[A-Za-z0-9+/]*={0,2}'` followed by a `raise`. A newer version may have a similar strict behaviour, https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/a87c46e/Modules/binascii.c#L427

Comment: @eelghEEz Oh yes I see that, that's only if `validate` is `True` (the default is `False`), so you'd have to opt into that behavior. Still a good thing to note.

Comment: This whole thing is a PITA. There seems to be a notion that the padding is mandatory. Wikipedia page makes a case that it is not. For big chunks (like images), the extra bytes are a drop in the bucket. But in other domains where text representation is desired, bandwidth is limited, and data is small, shaving the pad off might be considered optimal. Elixir/Erlang libraries seem to get this as they have an explicit `padding: false` option one can use. For python, I just went with the + b'========` which seems to work fine.

Comment: I think the minus (`-`) before `len` is a typo/error.  When I removed it, the code started working for me.

Comment: @JimFell Not sure why that would happen, works for me in Python 2 and 3. But that's the example I was saying _not_ to use anyway.

Answer (score 105):

As said in other responses, there are various ways in which base64 data could be corrupted.

However, as [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#Padding) says, removing the padding (the '=' characters at the end of base64 encoded data) is "lossless":

> From a theoretical point of view, the padding character is not needed,
>   since the number of missing bytes can be calculated from the number
>   of Base64 digits.

So if this is really the only thing "wrong" with your base64 data, the padding can just be added back. I came up with this to be able to parse "data" URLs in WeasyPrint, some of which were base64 without padding:

```
import base64
import re

def decode_base64(data, altchars=b'+/'):
    """Decode base64, padding being optional.

    :param data: Base64 data as an ASCII byte string
    :returns: The decoded byte string.

    """
    data = re.sub(rb'[^a-zA-Z0-9%s]+' % altchars, b'', data)  # normalize
    missing_padding = len(data) % 4
    if missing_padding:
        data += b'='* (4 - missing_padding)
    return base64.b64decode(data, altchars)
```

Tests for this function: [weasyprint/tests/test_css.py#L68](https://github.com/Kozea/WeasyPrint/blob/c521322ee763d6f9f5791b6f26d69cbc61f2470d/weasyprint/tests/test_css.py#L68)

Comment: Note: ASCII not Unicode, so to be safe, you might want to `str(data)`

Comment: This is good with a one caveat. base64.decodestring is deprecated, use base64.b64_decode

Comment: To clarify on @ariddell comment `base64.decodestring` has been deprecated for `base64.decodebytes` in Py3 but for version compatibility better to use `base64.b64decode`.

Comment: Because the `base64` module does ignore invalid non-base64 characters in the input, you first have to *normalise*  the data. Remove anything that's not a letter, digit `/` or `+`, and *then* add the padding.

Comment: `added back` it was never missing in the first place.

Comment: Having `4n+1` of normalized (unpadded) encoded input letters is already a sign of invalid encoding because base64 encodes only into `4n`, `4n+2` or `4n+3` unpadded letters.

Answer (score 55):

Just add padding as required. Heed Michael's warning, however.

```
b64_string += "=" * ((4 - len(b64_string) % 4) % 4) #ugh
```

Comment: There's surely something simpler that maps 0 to 0, 2 to 1 and 1 to 2.

Comment: Why are you expanding to a multiple of 3 instead of 4?

Comment: That's what the wikipedia article on base64 seems to imply.

Comment: @bp: In base64 encoding each 24 bits (3 bytes) binary input is encoded as 4 bytes output. output_len % 3 makes no sense.

Comment: Just appending `===` always works. Any extra `=` chars are seemingly safely discarded by Python.

Comment: Dankje for the one-liner! Why the inner modulo though? `((4 - len(b64_string)) % 4)` seems to return the same results for all values, including edge cases like len=0.

Comment: ^ the results of `4 - x % 4` are in range [0,3]

Comment: Thank you much !!  Worked wonderfully for Azure Communications which needs the correct padding to work =)

Answer (score 31):

Use

```
string += '=' * (-len(string) % 4)  # restore stripped '='s
```

Credit goes to a comment somewhere here.

```
>>> import base64

>>> enc = base64.b64encode('1')

>>> enc
>>> 'MQ=='

>>> base64.b64decode(enc)
>>> '1'

>>> enc = enc.rstrip('=')

>>> enc
>>> 'MQ'

>>> base64.b64decode(enc)
...
TypeError: Incorrect padding

>>> base64.b64decode(enc + '=' * (-len(enc) % 4))
>>> '1'

>>>
```

Comment: He means this comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2941995/python-ignore-incorrect-padding-error-when-base64-decoding#comment12174484_2942039

Answer (score 30):

"Incorrect padding" can mean not only "missing padding" but also (believe it or not) "incorrect padding".

If suggested "adding padding" methods don't work, try removing some trailing bytes:

```
lens = len(strg)
lenx = lens - (lens % 4 if lens % 4 else 4)
try:
    result = base64.decodestring(strg[:lenx])
except etc
```

Update: Any fiddling around adding padding or removing possibly bad bytes from the end should be done AFTER removing any whitespace, otherwise length calculations will be upset.

**It would be a good idea if you showed us a (short) sample of the data that you need to recover. Edit your question and copy/paste the result of** `print repr(sample)`.

Update 2: It is possible that the encoding has been done in an url-safe manner. If this is the case, you will be able to see minus and underscore characters in your data, and you should be able to decode it by using `base64.b64decode(strg, '-_')`

If you can't see minus and underscore characters in your data, but can see plus and slash characters, then you have some other problem, and may need the add-padding or remove-cruft tricks.

If you can see none of minus, underscore, plus and slash in your data, then you need to determine the two alternate characters; they'll be the ones that aren't in [A-Za-z0-9]. Then you'll need to experiment to see which order they need to be used in the 2nd arg of `base64.b64decode()`

**Update 3**: If your data is "company confidential":
(a) you should say so up front
(b) we can explore other avenues in understanding the problem, which is highly likely to be related to what characters are used instead of `+` and `/` in the encoding alphabet, or by other formatting or extraneous characters.

One such avenue would be to examine what non-"standard" characters are in your data, e.g.

```
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(int)
import string
s = set(string.ascii_letters + string.digits)
for c in your_data:
   if c not in s:
      d[c] += 1
print d
```

Comment: The data is comprised from the standard base64 character set. I'm pretty sure the problem is because 1 or more characters are missing - hence the padding error. Unless, there is a robust solution in Python, I'll go with my solution of calling openssl.

Comment: A "solution" that silently ignores errors is scarcely deserving of the term "robust". As I mentioned earlier, the various Python suggestions were methods of DEBUGGING to find out what the problem is, preparatory to a PRINCIPLED solution ... aren't you interested in such a thing?

Comment: My requirement is NOT to solve the problem of why the base64 is corrupt - it comes from a source I have no control over. My requirement is to provide information about the data received even if it is corrupt. One way to do this is to get the binary data out of the corrupt base64 so I can glean information from the underlying ASN.1. stream. I asked the original question because I wanted an answer to that question not the answer to another question - such as how to debug corrupt base64.

Comment: Just *normalize* the string, remove anything that is not a Base64 character. Anywhere, not just start or end.

Comment: This is the only answer that worked for me our of all the answers on this page

Answer (score 24):

If there's a padding error it probably means your string is corrupted; base64-encoded strings should have a multiple of four length. You can try adding the padding character (`=`) yourself to make the string a multiple of four, but it should already have that unless something is wrong

Comment: The underlying binary data is ASN.1. Even with corruption I want to get back to the binary because I can still get some useful info from the ASN.1 stream.

Comment: not true, if you want to decode a jwt for security checks, you will need it

Answer (score 14):

Incorrect padding error is caused because sometimes, metadata is also present in the encoded string
If your string looks something like: 'data:image/png;base64,...base 64 stuff....'
then you need to remove the first part before decoding it.

Say if you have image base64 encoded string, then try below snippet..

```
from PIL import Image
from io import BytesIO
from base64 import b64decode
imagestr = 'data:image/png;base64,...base 64 stuff....'
im = Image.open(BytesIO(b64decode(imagestr.split(',')[1])))
im.save("image.png")
```

Answer (score 7):

You can simply use `base64.urlsafe_b64decode(data)` if you are trying to decode a web image. It will automatically take care of the padding.

Comment: This is not my experience. At least not with 3.11.3.

Answer (score 4):

Check the documentation of the data source you're trying to decode. Is it possible that you meant to use `base64.urlsafe_b64decode(s)` instead of `base64.b64decode(s)`? That's one reason you might have seen this error message.

> Decode string s using a URL-safe alphabet, which substitutes - instead
>   of + and _ instead of / in the standard Base64 alphabet.

This is for example the case for various Google APIs, like Google's Identity Toolkit and Gmail payloads.

Comment: This does not answer the question at all.  Plus, `urlsafe_b64decode` also requires padding.

Comment: Well, there was an issue I had before answering this question, which was related to Google's Identity Toolkit. I was getting the incorrect padding error (I believe it was on the server) even tough the padding appeared to be correct. Turned out that I had to use `base64.urlsafe_b64decode`.

Comment: I agree that it doesn't answer the question, rdb, yet it was exactly what I needed to hear as well. I rephrased the answer to a bit nicer tone, I hope this works for you, Daniel.

Comment: Perfectly fine. I didn't notice that it sounded somewhat unkind, I only thought that it would be the quickest fix if it would fix the issue, and, for that reason, should be the first thing to be tried. Thanks for your change, it is welcome.

Answer (score 4):

In my case Gmail Web API was returning the email content as a base64 encoded string, but instead of encoded with the standard base64 characters/alphabet, it was encoded with the "web-safe" characters/alphabet variant of base64. The `+` and `/` characters are replaced with `-` and `_`. For python 3 use `base64.urlsafe_b64decode()`.

Answer (score 3):

Adding the padding is rather... fiddly.  Here's the function I wrote with the help of the comments in this thread as well as the wiki page for base64 (it's surprisingly helpful) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#Padding.

```
import logging
import base64
def base64_decode(s):
    """Add missing padding to string and return the decoded base64 string."""
    log = logging.getLogger()
    s = str(s).strip()
    try:
        return base64.b64decode(s)
    except TypeError:
        padding = len(s) % 4
        if padding == 1:
            log.error("Invalid base64 string: {}".format(s))
            return ''
        elif padding == 2:
            s += b'=='
        elif padding == 3:
            s += b'='
        return base64.b64decode(s)
```

Answer (score 3):

There are two ways to correct the input data described here, or, more specifically and in line with the OP, to make Python module base64's b64decode method able to process the input data to *something* without raising an un-caught exception:

1. Append == to the end of the input data and call base64.b64decode(...)
2. If that raises an exception, then

   i. Catch it via try/except,

   ii. (R?)Strip any = characters from the input data (N.B. this may not be necessary),

   iii. Append A== to the input data (A== through P== will work),

   iv. Call base64.b64decode(...) with those A==-appended input data

The result from Item 1. or Item 2. above will yield the desired result.

**Caveats**

This does not guarantee the decoded result will be what was originally encoded, but it will (sometimes?) give the OP enough to work with:

> Even with corruption I want to get back to the binary because I can still get some useful info from the ASN.1 stream").

See *What we know* and *Assumptions* below.

**TL;DR**

From some quick tests of base64.b64decode(...)

3. it appears that it ignores non-[A-Za-z0-9+/] characters; that includes ignoring =s **unless** they are the last character(s) in a parsed group of four, in which case the =s terminate the decoding (a=b=c=d= gives the same result as abc=, and a==b==c== gives the same result as ab==).
4. It also appears that **all** characters appended **are ignored** after the point where base64.b64decode(...) terminates decoding e.g. from an = as the fourth in a group.

As noted in several comments above, there are either zero, or one, or two, =s of padding required at the end of input data for when the [number of parsed characters to that point modulo 4] value is 0, or 3, or 2, respectively.  So, from items 3. and 4. above, appending two or more =s to the input data will correct any [Incorrect padding] problems in those cases.

**HOWEVER,** decoding cannot handle the case where the [total number of parsed characters modulo 4] is 1, because it takes a least two encoded characters to represent the first decoded byte in a group of three decoded bytes.  In **un**corrupted encoded input data, this [N modulo 4]=1 case never happens, but as the OP stated that characters may be missing, it could happen here.  That is why simply appending =s will not always work, and why appending **A**== will work when appending == does not.  N.B. Using [A] is all but arbitrary:  it adds only cleared (zero) bits to the decoded, which may or not be correct, but then the object here is not correctness but completion by base64.b64decode(...) sans exceptions.

**What we know** from the OP and especially subsequent comments is

- It is suspected that there are missing data (characters) in the
  Base64-encoded input data
- The Base64 encoding uses the standard 64 place-values plus padding:
  A-Z; a-z; 0-9; +; /; = is padding.  This is confirmed, or at least
  suggested, by the fact that `openssl enc ...` works.

**Assumptions**

- The input data contain only 7-bit ASCII data
- The only kind of corruption is missing encoded input data
- The OP does not care about decoded output data at any point after that corresponding to any missing encoded input data

**Github**

Here is a wrapper to implement this solution:

https://github.com/drbitboy/missing_b64

Answer (score 3):

This can be done in one line - no need to add temporary variables:

`b64decode(f"{s}{'=' * (4 - len(s) % 4)}")`

Answer (score 2):

I got this error without any use of base64. So i got a solution that error is in **localhost** it works fine on **127.0.0.1**

Comment: This answer does not seem related to the question. Could you please explain more in where the issue was located and how it is related?

Comment: I got this issue on django while running the application on my chrome browser. Normally django application run on localhost. But today it doesn't work on localhost So I have to change this **localhost** to **127.0.0.1** . So now its work.It also works on other browser like firefox without changing localhost

Comment: super odd, but this also worked for me - not sure why, but thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In case this error came from a web server: Try url encoding your post value. I was POSTing via "curl" and discovered I wasn't url-encoding my base64 value so characters like "+" were not escaped so the web server url-decode logic automatically ran url-decode and converted + to spaces.

"+" is a valid base64 character and perhaps the only character which gets mangled by an unexpected url-decode.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I faced that error while parsing an email. I got the attachment as base64 string and extract it via re.search. Eventually there was a strange additional substring at the end.

```
dHJhaWxlcgo8PCAvU2l6ZSAxNSAvUm9vdCAxIDAgUiAvSW5mbyAyIDAgUgovSUQgWyhcMDAyXDMz
MHtPcFwyNTZbezU/VzheXDM0MXFcMzExKShcMDAyXDMzMHtPcFwyNTZbezU/VzheXDM0MXFcMzEx
KV0KPj4Kc3RhcnR4cmVmCjY3MDEKJSVFT0YK

--_=ic0008m4wtZ4TqBFd+sXC8--
```

When I deleted `--_=ic0008m4wtZ4TqBFd+sXC8--` and strip the string then parsing was fixed up.

So my advise is make sure that you are decoding a correct base64 string.

Answer (score 1):

You should use

```
base64.b64decode(b64_string, ' /')
```

By default, the altchars are `'+/'`.

Comment: That does not work in python 3.7. assert len(altchars) == 2, repr(altchars)

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this problem as well and nothing worked.
I finally managed to find the solution which works for me. I had zipped content in base64 and this happened to 1 out of a million records...

This is a version of the solution suggested by Simon Sapin.

In case the padding is missing 3 then I remove the last 3 characters.

Instead of "0gA1RD5L/9AUGtH9MzAwAAA=="

We get "0gA1RD5L/9AUGtH9MzAwAA"

```
        missing_padding = len(data) % 4
        if missing_padding == 3:
            data = data[0:-3]
        elif missing_padding != 0:
            print ("Missing padding : " + str(missing_padding))
            data += '=' * (4 - missing_padding)
        data_decoded = base64.b64decode(data)
```

According to this answer [Trailing As in base64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18221065/tar-co-base64-output-contains-several-hundred-bytes-of-aaa-at-the-end) the reason is nulls. But I still have no idea why the encoder messes this up...

Comment: cannot believe that worked and adding additional '='s didn't. Mine ended with "T4NCg==" and no amount of adding or subtracting '='s made any difference until I removed the 'g' on the end. I notice 'g' != 'A'

Answer (score 1):

```py
def base64_decode(data: str) -> str:
    
    data = data.encode("ascii")

    rem = len(data) % 4

    if rem > 0:
        data += b"=" * (4 - rem)
    return base64.urlsafe_b64decode(data).decode('utf-8')
```

Comment: If you want to explain, please do so in your answer rather than in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Simply add additional characters like "=" or any other and make it a multiple of 4 before you try decoding the target string value. Something like;

```
if len(value) % 4 != 0: #check if multiple of 4
    while len(value) % 4 != 0:
        value = value + "="
    req_str = base64.b64decode(value)
else:
    req_str = base64.b64decode(value)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue trying to decode a base64 encoded image to/from a flask app.
The issue was that when trying to decode the string that got sent via a POST method, the string would be enclosed in b''. E.g. b'_9j_4AAQS' This needed to be removed to be able to be decoded.

```
#encoding code:
@bp.route("/someroute/", methods=('GET', 'POST'))
def someroute():
    fileb64 = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(file.read())
    return render_template('template.html', fileb64=fileb64)
```

---

```
#HTML form
        <form method="post" action="{{url_for('main.myroute')}}" class="inline">
            <input type="hidden" name="file" value="{{fileb64}}">
            <button type="submit" name="submit_param" value="submit_value" class="link-button">
                Download image in the correct format.
            </button>
          </form>
```

---

```
#decoding:
@bp.route('/myroute/', methods=('GET', 'POST'))
def myroute():
   fileb64 = request.form['file']
   file = base64.urlsafe_b64decode(fileb64[2:-1])
```

Answer (score -5):

Clear your browser cookie and recheck again, it should work.

Comment: This answer seems like it was supposed to be somewhere else, since there's no browser involved...?

Answer (score -6):

In my case I faced this error, after deleting the venv for the perticular project and it showing error for each fields so I tried by changing the BROWSER(Chrome to Edge), And actually it worked..