# Python: Incorrect Padding

Tags: python, base64, snapchat

I'm making a program that downloads snapchat stories.
And this:

```
base64.b64decode(snap['media_iv']))
```

Is getting the error `Error: Incorrect padding`

The actual media_iv is: `GhcakENDGbTNY6GzE1AV3w==`

---

```
from __future__ import print_function

import os.path
import sys
from getpass import getpass
import base64
from pprint import pprint

from docopt import docopt
from Tkinter import *

from pysnap import get_file_extension, Snapchat

def printsnaps():
    s = Snapchat()
    s.login(u.get(), p.get())
    for snap in s.get_friend_stories():
        pprint(snap)
        path = snap["id"]
        data = s.get_story_blob(snap['media_id'],
            base64.b64decode(snap['media_key']),
            base64.b64decode(snap['media_iv']))
        if data is None:
            continue
        with (openpath, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(data)
top = Tk()
u = StringVar()
p = StringVar()
user = Entry(top, text="usermame", textvariable=u)
user.pack()
pswd = Entry(top, text="password", textvariable=p)
pswd.pack()
logb = Button(top, text="login", width = 15, command=printsnaps)
logb.pack()

top.mainloop()
```

---

SOLUTION: Tutorial was wrong, it didnt need to be decoded

Comment: possible duplicate of [Decode python base64 String](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11656115/decode-python-base64-string)

Comment: Given that `GhcakENDGbTNY6GzE1AV3w==` decodes fine using `b64decode()` as well as `'GhcakENDGbTNY6GzE1AV3w=='.decode('bas464')`, how certain are you that `snap['media_iv']` is set to that value? Can you show us the output of `pprint(snap)`?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the string's inherited decode method:

```
str(snap['media_iv']).decode('base64')
```

I've tried decoding it, but it decodes to a bunch of binary nonsense, which shouldn't happen in the case of a SnapChat. Perhaps, your given value is incorrect.

Comment: If you try this, you will get an AttributeError thrown: `'str'` object has no attribute `'decode'`