# Decoding PNG DataURL urlopen vs base64decode

Tags: python, image, encoding, base64, data-url

I have PNG image coded to DataURL representation. It starts regularly: 
`u'data:image/png;base64,...` but it has no `==` ending. 
`base64.b64decode` raises `TypeError: Incorrect padding`, but `urllib.urlopen` returns proper value - an image which successfully opens by image viewer.

Here is that encoded string: 
http://www.sendspace.com/file/8l61im

Its difficult to formulate actual question here - I just wonder what is the reason of that issue - is it particular buggy string, and `urlopen` just has more 'tolerant' algorithm, or something else? Kindly help!

upd
Tried `urlsafe_b64decode` - and with it I got:
`TypeError: character mapping must return integer, None or unicode`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2941995/python-ignore-incorrect-padding-error-when-base64-decoding