# Issues with B64 decoding

Tags: python, gmail-api

Using the non-mime message.get method, I am pulling out the body/data and trying to decode it in order to simply show the message in english. The problem I am having is that some of the messages decode fine, and then suddenly I get incorrect padding issues. I have tried replacing + and / to no avail.

Why would this be happening and how do I fix it?

Here's my messages.get method:

```
try:
message = service.users().messages().get(userId=user_id, id=msg_id).execute()

# Pull Raw Message Body from Response
message_raw = message['payload']['parts'][0]['body']['data']

# Decode the raw message
message_decoded = base64.b64decode(message_raw)

# Print the messages
print message_decoded
```

UPDATES

Service

```
gmail_service = build('gmail', 'v1', http=http)
```

Traceback Error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "gmail.py", line 166, in <module>
GetMessage(gmail_service, 'me', message_id)
File "gmail.py", line 155, in GetMessage
message_decoded = base64.b64decode(message_raw)
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/base64.py",        line 76, in b64decode
raise TypeError(msg)
TypeError: Incorrect padding
```

Traceback error when using urlsafe

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "gmail.py", line 166, in <module>
GetMessage(gmail_service, 'me', message_id)
File "gmail.py", line 155, in GetMessage
message_decoded = base64.urlsafe_b64decode(message_raw)
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/base64.py", line 112, in urlsafe_b64decode
return b64decode(s, '-_')
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/base64.py", line 71, in b64decode
s = _translate(s, {altchars[0]: '+', altchars[1]: '/'})
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/base64.py", line 36, in _translate
return s.translate(''.join(translation)) 
TypeError: character mapping must return integer, None or unicode
```

Comment: What kind of error are you getting? Include the traceback.

Comment: You sould also show an example of preblematic message.

Comment: What module are you using; that is, what is the type of `service`?

Comment: `+` and `/` are the 63rd and 64th characters in Base-64 (along with 52 letters and 10 digits).  Padding refers to the presence or absence of `=` signs (0, 1 or 2 needed) at the end of a Base-64 string.  Some systems are careless about adding the correct padding.

Comment: Thanks for the comments: @msw and Serge I've added the traceback. msw Not completely sure if that's what you wanted to see (see 'Service' in my updates'). Jonathan - thanks for the info, it does look like all the messages end in an '=', but perhaps there aren't enough...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2941995/python-ignore-incorrect-padding-error-when-base64-decoding Seen that already?

Comment: @SergeBallesta Added in traceback

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to use:

```
message_decoded = base64.urlsafe_b64decode(message_raw)
```

since the raw message is URLSafe base64 encoded.

Comment: When I use that this is the following error (Traceback in original post): TypeError: character mapping must return integer, None or unicode

Comment: I think I figured it out - I needed to convert message_raw to a str before passing it into the urlsafe method.