# Converting base64 to an image: incorrect padding error

Tags: python, base64

I'm receiving an image from a form in base64 which I would like to convert back to a PNG file type.

To do this I tried the following methods

```
attempt1 = base64.b64decode(picture.data)
attempt2 = picture.data.decode('base64')
```

but I received the error `Error: Incorrect padding`.

I saw [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9807138/2961662) and tried using the function however I get the same error.

What can I do to fix this issue? Thanks.

**Edit**

my base64 image looks like this (The list of characters are much longer):

```
data:image/png;base64, OouhoGUiyf+YdiHl==
```

Comment: Maybe you could provide some information about the data you have, how many characters is it? Does it end with a series of `=`?

Comment: Did you exclude the `data:image/png;base64, ` part from your decoding procedure?

Comment: What part of the string are you passing in to be decoded? The "data" in your example is `OouhoGUiyf+YdiHl==`, nothing more, nothing less.

Comment: @jojonas I'm not excluding the `data:image/png;base64, ` part. I'm guessing I should now? Maybe using regex?

Comment: @JeffMercado Good guess. @jojonas There is no need for regex here. A simple `str.split` or manual offset (by using `str.find`), by looking for the comma should do its job.

Comment: @HelloWorld That works perfectly, thanks for the input.

Comment: @HelloWorld, could you please post your comments as an answer so Pav Sidhu can mark it as solved?

Answer (score 3):

It seems that your data is a [DataURL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs) scheme

> Data URLs are composed of four parts: a prefix (data:), a MIME type indicating the type of data, an optional base64 token if non-textual, and the data itself:

```
data:[<mediatype>][;base64],<data>
```

You should extract only the `<data>` part from your string:

```
base64.decodebytes(picture.data.split(",")[1])
```