# How to decode base64 in python3

Tags: python, base64

I have a base64 encrypt code, and I can't decode in python3.5

```
import base64
code = "YWRtaW46MjAyY2I5NjJhYzU5MDc1Yjk2NGIwNzE1MmQyMzRiNzA" # Unencrypt is 202cb962ac59075b964b07152d234b70
base64.b64decode(code)
```

Result:

```
binascii.Error: Incorrect padding
```

But same website([base64decode](http://www.base64decode.org)) can decode it,

Please anybody can tell me why, and how to use python3.5 decode it?

Thanks

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Base64 needs a string with length multiple of 4. If the string is short, it is padded with 1 to 3 `=`.

```
import base64
code = "YWRtaW46MjAyY2I5NjJhYzU5MDc1Yjk2NGIwNzE1MmQyMzRiNzA="
base64.b64decode(code)
# b'admin:202cb962ac59075b964b07152d234b70'
```

Comment: the output object is a byte, how do I get it to be string?

Comment: @ScipioAfricanus: you have to decode it, with the correct encoding.

Answer (score 11):

According to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2942039/6495334), you can just add the required padding.

```
code = "YWRtaW46MjAyY2I5NjJhYzU5MDc1Yjk2NGIwNzE1MmQyMzRiNzA"
b64_string = code
b64_string += "=" * ((4 - len(b64_string) % 4) % 4)
base64.b64decode(b64_string) #'admin:202cb962ac59075b964b07152d234b70'
```

Comment: The answer I gave adds the appropriate padding based on length of the encoded string. Please accept the answer if you found it helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I tried the other way around. If you know what the unencrypted value is:

```
>>> import base64
>>> unencoded = b'202cb962ac59075b964b07152d234b70'
>>> encoded = base64.b64encode(unencoded)
>>> print(encoded)
b'MjAyY2I5NjJhYzU5MDc1Yjk2NGIwNzE1MmQyMzRiNzA='
>>> decoded = base64.b64decode(encoded)
>>> print(decoded)
b'202cb962ac59075b964b07152d234b70'
```

Now you see the correct padding. `b'MjAyY2I5NjJhYzU5MDc1Yjk2NGIwNzE1MmQyMzRiNzA=`

Answer (score 0):

It actually seems to just be that `code` is incorrectly [padded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#Padding) (`code` is incomplete)

```
import base64
code = "YWRtaW46MjAyY2I5NjJhYzU5MDc1Yjk2NGIwNzE1MmQyMzRiNzA"
base64.b64decode(code+"=")
```

returns `b'admin:202cb962ac59075b964b07152d234b70'`