# binascii.Error: Incorrect padding, even when string length is multiple of 4

Tags: python, python-2.7, base64

I am trying to convert base64 string to image by python code, but I am getting **binascii.Error: Incorrect padding** I have gone through with my [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9807138) but they only suggest check string length is divisible 4, if not make it divisible by 4 by adding  '=' characters at the end of base64 encoded sting. 
Please help in this.

[PYTHON CODE:](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0iJEAXqbN2Ickg5bEJ6Q1pZcVU/view?usp=sharing) (please check code from drive for more visibility)

```
import base64

strOne= 'data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSU...string has 200000 character thats why I couldn t paste'
 print 'strOne Length',len(strOne)
 print 'StrOne Length is completely divisible by 4 (len%4),(len/4):', len(strOne)%4,len(strOne)/4

 with open("imageToSave.png", "wb") as fh:
     fh.write(strOne.strip().decode('base64'))
```

output:

```
strOne Length 200000
StrOne Length is completely divisible by 4 (len%4),(len/4): 0 50000
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tests.py", line 13, in <module>
    fh.write(strOne.strip().decode('base64'))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/encodings/base64_codec.py", line 42, in base64_decode
    output = base64.decodestring(input)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/base64.py", line 328, in decodestring
    return binascii.a2b_base64(s)
binascii.Error: Incorrect padding
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

by checking your link, your string has 200000 bytes all right, *but* it contains the header:

```
strOne = b"data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSU...
```

This is part of MIME message or something. You have to strip this first.

```
strOne = strOne.partition(",")[2]
```

then pad (if needed)

```
pad = len(strOne)%4
strOne += b"="*pad
```

then decode using `codecs` (python 3 compliant)

```
codecs.decode(strOne.strip(),'base64')
```

=> "we believe in team work" :)