# Google Drive OAuth2 : "state" with multiple parameters

Tags: python-2.7, oauth-2.0, google-drive-api, google-oauth

GDrive OAuth allows for a state parameter to be passed from the request to the response callback. When I send a string that contains a single token, it works as expected, but if I send a json, then I can't seem to read back the value from the state parameter in the callback function.

I have tried using base64.encodestring(), base64.urlsafe_b64encode() and the decode versions of the these functions in the callback but then I get an "Incorrect Padding" error on decode.

To correct this, I tried the following snippet I found on StackOverflow:

```
`stateStr += "=" * ((4 - len(stateStr) % 4) % 4)`
`stateList = base64.urlsafe_b64decode(stateStr)`
```

But I still get the "Incorrect Padding" error.

Any help will be appreciated,

Thanks

***EDIT***
The workaround to this problem was for me to separate the strings by using a '|' char. That way I'm still passing a single string which works fine without any padding errors.
***EDIT***

Answer (score 0):

Based from this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2941995/python-ignore-incorrect-padding-error-when-base64-decoding), there are various ways in which base64 data could be corrupted. It was stated [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#Padding) that the padding character is not needed, since the number of missing bytes can be calculated from the number of Base64 digits.

> If there's a padding error it probably means your string is corrupted; base64-encoded strings should have a multiple of four length. You can try adding the padding character (=) yourself to make the string a multiple of four, but it should already have that unless something is wrong.