# Finding the url of a dynamically generated link in python

Tags: python, parsing, web-scraping, python-requests

I have a dynamic link, e.g. 
https://news.google.com/__i/rss/rd/articles/CBMiiQFodHRwczovL3d3dy5jb3JyaWVyZS5pdC9zcG9ydC8xOV9vdHRvYnJlXzMwL3JhcGluYXRvcmktdmlsbGEtY2xhdWRpby1tYXJjaGlzaW8taW5nZW50ZS1ib3R0aW5vLTQ1YmE0YjFlLWZhZTctMTFlOS1iMWM2LWEzODFhYmJhNWQ5Zi5zaHRtbNIBjAFodHRwczovL3d3dy5jb3JyaWVyZS5pdC9zcG9ydC8xOV9vdHRvYnJlXzMwL3JhcGluYXRvcmktdmlsbGEtY2xhdWRpby1tYXJjaGlzaW8taW5nZW50ZS1ib3R0aW5vLTQ1YmE0YjFlLWZhZTctMTFlOS1iMWM2LWEzODFhYmJhNWQ5Zl9hbXAuaHRtbA?oc=5

I want to find the last generated link in python. I can't seem to find a solution, any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that the target URL is encoded in base64.

```
>>> from base64 import urlsafe_b64decode
>>> urlsafe_b64decode('CBMiiQFodHRwczovL3d3dy5jb3JyaWVyZS5pdC9zcG9ydC8xOV9vdHRvYnJlXzMwL3JhcGluYXRvcmktdmlsbGEtY2xhdWRpby1tYXJjaGlzaW8taW5nZW50ZS1ib3R0aW5vLTQ1YmE0YjFlLWZhZTctMTFlOS1iMWM2LWEzODFhYmJhNWQ5Zi5zaHRtbNIBjAFodHRwczovL3d3dy5jb3JyaWVyZS5pdC9zcG9ydC8xOV9vdHRvYnJlXzMwL3JhcGluYXRvcmktdmlsbGEtY2xhdWRpby1tYXJjaGlzaW8taW5nZW50ZS1ib3R0aW5vLTQ1YmE0YjFlLWZhZTctMTFlOS1iMWM2LWEzODFhYmJhNWQ5Zl9hbXAuaHRtbA==')
b'\x08\x13"\x89\x01https://www.corriere.it/sport/19_ottobre_30/rapinatori-villa-claudio-marchisio-ingente-bottino-45ba4b1e-fae7-11e9-b1c6-a381abba5d9f.shtml\xd2\x01\x8c\x01https://www.corriere.it/sport/19_ottobre_30/rapinatori-villa-claudio-marchisio-ingente-bottino-45ba4b1e-fae7-11e9-b1c6-a381abba5d9f_amp.html'
```

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at this thread: [How to scrape Google News articles content from Google News RSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56829861/how-to-scrape-google-news-articles-content-from-google-news-rss)

At the bottom the print the url and I think thats the value you are looking for. Hope it helps!

Comment: Can't really get that to work. Seems like that is helpful for a feed, while I am looking to obtain a final link, from a link.