# Convert base64 converted image from java client in python server

Tags: python, sockets

I had sent an image that is encoded it to Base64 in Java to python, and when I got the data from python, this is the data

> 'iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAMMAAAEECAIAAAAahxdFAAAAA3NCSVQICAjb4U/gAAAgAElEQVR4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\nxBiwPaJRL25TDiG'

How do I convert this to either bitmap or an image in python? If the code snippets are needed, please tell

I had tried using `base64.b64decode` and it gives the error incorrect padding

Based on one of the comments, I tried `base64.b64decode(base64_str + '===')` and gotten this

> b'\x89PNG\r\n\x1a\n\x00\x00\x00\rIHDR\x00\x00\x00\xc3\x00\x00\x01\x04\x08\x02\x00\x00\x00\x1a\x87\x17E\x00\x00\x00\x03sBIT\x08\x08\x08\xdb\xe1O\xe0\x00\x00
> \x00IDATx\x9c\x94\xbc\xddrdI\x92\xa4\xa7j\xe6~"\x90Y5US5\xdd=?|\x02^S\xf6\xfd\x1feeE\xb8\xec\xed\xee\xea\xaa\xcaLD\xc4q7S\xe5\xc5A\xf3\x86\xe4\x92\x03\x88\x00\x02\x08
> q"\xdc\x8e\xfd\xa8~\x16\xfc_\xff\xcb\xff\x06gD0\x14\x11\x89\x1b3\x8a\xfd9'\xc9\xceAL\x04oG\x94\xf6m\xde\xe7q\xd8\xbc\xe7-#t?\x9e\xd4\xcfyS\xceO\xe3\xf0\xc1\xdb\xedv\x8c\xf1\xc3\xdbQo\xf3\x9e7\xc13\x8f\x18\xbe3s\x1c\x9f\x8e\x999\x01\x1co\xc7\x18\xe36\xe6\x88\x9c\xb7q\xbf\xddn\xb7\xe3\xed\xed\xed\xc7\x1f\xbe\xff\x97\x1f~\xf8tL\xfc'?L\xfc\xf2\xfb\xb7\xbf\xfc\xed\xef\x7f\xf9\xdb\xdf\xaa\xca\x80\xa4\x86\x01\x10S\x92\x89\xcclX6\x1d\x0f\xed\xbd\x95\x99\x92\x8e1\x11\xb2a3\xc2\x00nd[\x81\xdcP\x18\xc8\x904\x83[\xb6\r
> a\x07mJ\n\x8b$\x00\xb7\x00\xb4E\xa8\xbb'!
> \x80\xdd\x1d@\x80I\xad2\xc9\xe1n\x17I\xb7(7:\x15\xee\x06\xa4\x8e\xd5u\x9e\xfbQ\xfb\xf1<\xdf_\xef_\x1e\xef:\xd9\xddR-\x00r\x9a,\xe5\xc0\xb3;\xd4;\x80\xd6\x00_\xab\xdf\x8e\xe3\xac\x1d\x8dR\x87\xad\xa6Lj-\xb4\xdb\x98\xf9~.\x90\xec\x8f\xab\x1a\xe6\xc3\xeb\xd3\x1e\x95\xb5\na=\xa5\x99}\x9f\xb8a\xbe\xdd\x8f\xc8\xfe\xf4\xe9~\x8c\x81\xc1\xa0\xbb\xeb<\xcfok\xd7\xf2\xde\xcfD\xde\xd5\x8b\xdd}\xe6\xcf\xff\xf6\xc7c\xde\x97\xbb\r2"A\x12\xa4\x18`\x87\x91\xe1\x88\xc1\xe1[\x8c\x1c\xa9\x08\x8e19\xd6\xc0\xfd>\xb1\x15s\x98\x18\x11i\xcc7\x98\x9d\xc7q\xe41@\x96FF\x98\x91#\x02\x02\xaa\xeb~\x1c\xb2g\xa4$\'\x03\x90\r0#Z\xde\xea\x91c\xce\xc1\xffL$\x11`\x84\xd4\xaf\xd7z\x9e\xbb\xbbl\xcb&\t\x87)\xc0\x80i\x1b\xd7y7\x0c\x19\x80d\xc12\x1c\xb4\xa4
> a%\xc3\x06\xc9\x88\x80\x1b\x82\xd4\xa0\x80\xb8B'\x05\xb8\x08\x02\x08\xda\xeav;#\xd4p\x83\x0e\x90\xb2\x01\xd8\x90\xd1\x92[-\x03\x81V\xcb\xf2u\x91av5\xdce\xb5\xb4\xbb\xbf<\x9f\xe7y>\xcegm\xac\xf3l\xe1\xb1_\x13\xa4]\xb5C\xa8\xae\xb3\xfbN\x08ZB\x16\xc5\xe8\xee\xf7\xbdb\x8c\xd1\xf1\xdc[\xaa\x01\xb7\xfb\x86h\xc0f\xef}\xb6\x07\x83\xec\xb6\x06\x93\x11\xd9H\xb9\xdc\n\xd0
> x'?}\xbe\xff\xe9\x87\x1f\x7f\xfa\xe7\xcf?~\xf7\xf9~\x9b\x99\x98\x19I\xbe\xd6\xd9\xdd\xab\xb1\xd6\xbe\x8d\x94\\xd1\x141F\xfe\xe9\x7f\xf9\xf7fX\xce\x08\xdb#SIY\x86\xcc\x18s\x9e\xbd\xe7\x18s\x1eB\xde8+|\x8b\xe0`r\xb4\xd6\xdb\xed\xd3@\x1c\x11\xe3\x00\x88\xc1\xf8<\xde\xc0\xb0tv!'

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python: Ignore 'Incorrect padding' error when base64 decoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2941995/python-ignore-incorrect-padding-error-when-base64-decoding)

Comment: `base64.b64decode(base64_str + b'===')`

Comment: @GordonAitchJay I tried that but only strings are accepted, do I try just `===` instead?

Comment: @GordonAitchJay I tried with `===` and gotten the part I added to my question

Comment: Ah yes, sorry. The operands must be the same type: `str + str` or `bytes + bytes`.

Comment: You now need to write that to file: `with open("picture.png", "wb") as f: f.write(base64.b64decode(base64_str + "==="))`

Comment: @GordonAitchJay Sorry for the late reply, but is that code for creating a picture file called **picture.png** using write?

Comment: Correct. It would save it in the current working directory.