# Convert utf-8 string to base64

Tags: python, base64

I converted base64 str1= `eyJlbXBsb3llciI6IntcIm5hbWVcIjpcInVzZXJzX2VtcGxveWVyXCIsXCJhcmdzXCI6XCIxMDQ5NTgxNjI4MzdcIn0ifQ`

to str2=`{"employer":"{\"name\":\"users_employer\",\"args\":\"104958162837\"}"}`

with help of http://www.online-decoder.com/ru

I want to convert str2 to str1 with help of python. My code:

```
import base64

data = """{"employer":"{"name":"users_employer","args":"104958162837"}"}"""
encoded_bytes = base64.b64encode(data.encode("utf-8"))
encoded_str = str(encoded_bytes, "utf-8")
print(encoded_str)
```

The code prints str3=

```
eyJlbXBsb3llciI6InsibmFtZSI6InVzZXJzX2VtcGxveWVyIiwiYXJncyI6IjEwNDk1ODE2MjgzNyJ9In0=
```

What should I change in code to print **str1** instead of **str3** ?

I tried

```
{"employer":"{\"name\":\"users_employer\",\"args\":\"104958162837\"}"}
```

and

```
{"employer":"{"name":"users_employer","args":"104958162837"}"}
```

but result is the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `\"` is a python escape sequence for the single character `"`. The fix is to keep the backslashes and use a raw string (note the "r" at the front).

```
data = r"""{"employer":"{\"name\":\"users_employer\",\"args\":\"104958162837\"}"}"""
```

This will be the original string, except that python pads base64 numbers to 4 character multiples with the "=" sign. Strip the padding and you have the original.

```
import base64

str1 = "eyJlbXBsb3llciI6IntcIm5hbWVcIjpcInVzZXJzX2VtcGxveWVyXCIsXCJhcmdzXCI6XCIxMDQ5NTgxNjI4MzdcIn0ifQ"
str1_decoded = base64.b64decode(str1 + "="*divmod(len(str1),4)[1]).decode("ascii")
print("str1", str1_decoded)

data = r"""{"employer":"{\"name\":\"users_employer\",\"args\":\"104958162837\"}"}"""
encoded_bytes = base64.b64encode(data.encode("utf-8"))
encoded_str = str(encoded_bytes.rstrip(b"="), "utf-8")
print("my encoded", encoded_str)
print("same?", str1 == encoded_str)
```

Answer (score 1):

The results you want are just `base64.b64decode(str1 + "==")`.  See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2941995/python-ignore-incorrect-padding-error-when-base64-decoding) for more information on the padding.

Comment: I did ```data = data + "=="
encoded_bytes = base64.b64encode(data.encode("utf-8"))```
But result is not good(. What I did wrong?

Comment: The python decoder requires that you pad the string with "=", but the unpadded string is different up to the pad point. Just adding padding won't change the fact that they are different.