# java base64.deocde to python3

Tags: java, python-3.x

I have a piece of java code

```
    enter code here
    byte[] random1 = Base64.getDecoder().decode(arr.getString(2));
    byte[] test1 = "/bCN99cbY13kwEf+wnRErg".getBytes(StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1);
    System.out.println(test1.length);    // #22
    System.out.println(Base64.getDecoder().decode(test1).length);    // #16
```

I am trying to use python3 and I get an error.

```
    text = bytes("/bCN99cbY13kwEf+wnRErg", encoding='iso-8859-1')
    print(len(base64.b64decode(text)))

    # Traceback (most recent call last):

    # File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\base64.py", line                 
    # 546, in decodebytes
    #    return binascii.a2b_base64(s)
    # binascii.Error: Incorrect padding
```

How can I use python3 to implement the functions on the java code to achieve decode length=16

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your Base64 encoded array is missing the [padding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#Output_padding), which is not always required.

It is no problem in Java as the `Decoder` does not require it:

> The Base64 padding character '=' is accepted and interpreted as the end of the encoded byte data, but is not required.

In contrast, the Python `b64decode(s)` method requires the padding and throws an error if it is missing.

> A binascii.Error exception is raised if s is incorrectly padded.

I found a simple solution in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49459036/7947994): Always adding the maximum padding at the end of the byte array (two equal signs `==`). The `b64decode(s)` method simply ignores the padding if it is too long and so it always works.

You only have to change your code slightly for it to work:

```
text = bytes("/bCN99cbY13kwEf+wnRErg", encoding='iso-8859-1')
padded_text = text + b'=='
result = base64.b64decode(padded_text)

print(len(result))
```

The output is `16` identical to the Java output.