Extract URL from Google News Rss feed
I had a code that was extracting a Google Rss URL, but that is not working. It looks like Google has changed the encoding of the URL.
Example URL:
"https://news.google.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?oc=5"
Code that was working previously:

_ENCODED_URL_PREFIX = "https://news.google.com/rss/articles/"
_ENCODED_URL_RE = re.compile(fr"^{re.escape(_ENCODED_URL_PREFIX)}(?P<encoded_url>[^?]+)")
_DECODED_URL_RE = re.compile(rb'^\x08\x13".+?(?P<primary_url>http[^\xd2]+)\xd2\x01')


    @functools.lru_cache(2048)
    def _decode_google_news_url(self, url: str) -> str:
        match = _ENCODED_URL_RE.match(url)
        encoded_text = match.groupdict()["encoded_url"]  # type: ignore
        encoded_text += "==="  # Fix incorrect padding. Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49459036/
        decoded_text = base64.urlsafe_b64decode(encoded_text)

        match = _DECODED_URL_RE.match(decoded_text)
        primary_url = match.groupdict()["primary_url"]  # type: ignore
        primary_url = primary_url.decode()
        return primary_url


There is a very interesting solution that someone wrote on Github:
fetchDecodedBatchExecute
const fetchDecodedBatchExecute = (id: string): Promise<string> => {
  const s =
    '[[["Fbv4je","[\\"garturlreq\\",[[\\"en-US\\",\\"US\\",[\\"FINANCE_TOP_INDICES\\",\\"WEB_TEST_1_0_0\\"],null,null,1,1,\\"US:en\\",null,180,null,null,null,null,null,0,null,null,[1608992183,723341000]],\\"en-US\\",\\"US\\",1,[2,3,4,8],1,0,\\"655000234\\",0,0,null,0],\\"' +
    id +
    '\\"]",null,"generic"]]]'

  return fetch("https://news.google.com/_/DotsSplashUi/data/batchexecute?" + "rpcids=Fbv4je", {
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8",
      Referrer: "https://news.google.com/"
    },
    body: "f.req=" + encodeURIComponent(s),
    method: "POST"
  })
    .then(e => e.text())
    .then(s => {
      const header = '[\\"garturlres\\",\\"'
      const footer = '\\",'
      if (!s.includes(header)) {
        throw new Error("header not found: " + s)
      }
      const start = s.substring(s.indexOf(header) + header.length)
    
      if (!start.includes(footer)) {
        throw new Error("footer not found")
      }

      const url = start.substring(0, start.indexOf(footer))
      return url
    })
}

decodeGoogleNewsUrl
export const decodeGoogleNewsUrl = async (sourceUrl: string): Promise<string | null> => {
  const url = new URL(sourceUrl)
  const path = url.pathname.split("/")
  if (
    url.hostname === "news.google.com" &&
    path.length > 1 &&
    path[path.length - 2] === "articles"
  ) {
    const base64 = path[path.length - 1]
    
    if (!isValidBase64(base64)) {
      return null
      //throw new Error("Invalid base64 string");
    }

    let str = atob(base64)

    const prefix = Buffer.from([0x08, 0x13, 0x22]).toString("binary")
    if (str.startsWith(prefix)) {
      str = str.substring(prefix.length)
    }

    const suffix = Buffer.from([0xd2, 0x01, 0x00]).toString("binary")
    if (str.endsWith(suffix)) {
      str = str.substring(0, str.length - suffix.length)
    }

    const bytes = Uint8Array.from(str, c => c.charCodeAt(0))
    const len = bytes.at(0)!
    if (len >= 0x80) {
      str = str.substring(2, len + 2)
    } else {
      str = str.substring(1, len + 1)
    }

    if (str.startsWith("AU_yqL")) {
      const url = await fetchDecodedBatchExecute(base64)
      return url
    }

    return str
  } else {
    return sourceUrl
  }
}

I additionally added a base64 string validator
const isValidBase64 = (str: string): boolean => {
  const base64Regex = /^[A-Za-z0-9+/=]+$/;
  return base64Regex.test(str);
}

thanks to huksley!
See the original post:

It's rate limited btw

in case this is useful to anyone, the "naive" method consisting of making a GET and checking for redirects, (e.g. with python's requests r = requests.get(url) and checking r.history ), fails.
But this worked for me
